# how to create unique array from array

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

Array

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [a1] => 12
        [v1] => 3100.00
        [v2] => 186.00
        [v3] => 186.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [a1] => 12
        [v1] => 1200.00
        [v2] => 72.00
        [v3] => 72.00
    )
```

i want to create new array from this array
which is look like this as given below it should give me '12' common and add other values

Array

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [a1] => 12
        [v1] => 4300.00
        [v2] => 258.00
        [v3] => 258.00
    )
```

Comment: You want to sum the fields of each array together and make a product array?  You can do this easily with a foreach loop, maybe try and do this first yourself and then we can help you

Comment: Can it be assumed that each of the original arrays have the same length?

Comment: yes @joshuamiller ...the length will be same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try This code ,
foreach($value as $i=>$v) {
    $temp[0]['a1'] = $v['a1'];
    $temp[0]['v1'] += $v['v1'];
    $temp[0]['v2'] += $v['v2'];
    $temp[0]['v3'] += $v['v3'];

}
```

Comment: OP the source array is multidimensional, your $yourArray not (-;

Comment: Without $temp[0]['v1'], or ['v2'], or ['v3'] being previously declared, a += operator will throw an Undefined Variable notice.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code:

```
<?php
        $merged = array();
        $res =  array('a1'=>12,'v1'=>3100.00,'v2'=>186.00,'v3'=>186.00);
        $res1 = array('a1'=>12,'v1'=>1200.00,'v2'=>72.00,'v3'=>72.00);

        foreach ([$res, $res1] as $a) {                             // iterate both arrays
            foreach ($a as $key => $value) {                     // iterate all keys+values
                $merged[$key] = $value + (isset($merged[$key]) ? $merged[$key] : 0);   // merge and add
            }
        }

    print "<pre>";
    print_r($merged); 
    die;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear the real your needs, so this solution only one of a few possible solutions.

This script `a1` element is using as key, so it will work  with more than one `a1` value.

Example:

```
<?php
$a = [
    [
        'a1' => 12,
        'v1' => 3100.00,
        'v2' => 186.00,
        'v3' => 186.00,
    ],
    [
        'a1' => 12,
        'v1' => 1200.00,
        'v2' => 72.00,
        'v3' => 72.00,
    ],
    [
        'a1' => 13,
        'v1' => 2100.00,
        'v2' => 386.00,
        'v3' => 386.00,
    ],
    [
        'a1' => 13,
        'v1' => 1200.00,
        'v2' => 72.00,
        'v3' => 72.00,
    ]
];

$r = [];
foreach ($a as $item) {
    $key = $item['a1'];
    if (empty($r[$key]))
        $r[$key] = $item;
    else {
        foreach ($item as $k => $v) {
            if ($k !== 'a1')
                $r[$key][$k] = empty($r[$key][$k]) ? $item[$k] : $r[$key][$k] + $item[$k];
        }
    }
}

print_r(array_values($r));
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple foreach loop can do it.

```
$result = array();
foreach($yourArray as $arr){
    foreach($arr as $i=>$v) {
        if(!isset($result[$i])) {
            $result[$i] = 0;
        }
        if($i == 'a1'){ 
            $result[$i] = $v;
        } else {
            $result[$i] += $v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP the source array is multidimensional, your `$yourArray` not (-;